# nginx how to proxy_pass all requests expect one directory?

Tags: nginx

I have an Angular 9 app (SSR) on my server and a PHP based REST api (Slim) in a subdirectory.

What I'm trying to do is that all incoming requests shall be handled by my Angular application. But one directory is for a REST-api that have to be excluded.

My current nginx config locks like this:

```
location ~ /rest {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /rest/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ^~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
}
```

The requests to the REST api responds with the correct content. But all calls to `http://127.0.0.1:4000` comes with a `504 gateway timeout`. So what I would like to achieve is:

```
https://SERVER       -> http://127.0.0.1:4000
https://SERVER/xyz   -> http://127.0.0.1:4000
...
https://SERVER/rest  -> http://127.0.0.1/rest
```

How can do a proxy forward off all requests but not if a specific directory is given?

Comment: Are all requests to `/rest/...` always served with the same script, `/rest/index.php`? Or there can be requests for some static content or other PHP scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use regulare expression locations unless you need them.

You should use these versions:

```
location /rest {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /rest/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
}
```

If you get 504 Gateway timeout errors, then you need to check the application listening at `127.0.0.1:4000` port.